# A question regarding the Layered Architecture

Tags: software-engineering

Consider the following general form of a layered architecture :

[image]

I need to check my understanding about the second layer from top . More specifically I need to check my understanding the regarding the meaning of "User interface management " . According to my understanding , UI management is the code that underlies the UI , for example it is the code for each button and each UI elements . So for example , let us consider that the user needs to generate a report from a system that uses this layered pattern as its architecture. So what happens is the user press the generate report button then the underlying code of this button knows that it need to run the code of generate report system functionality ( which exists in the third layer). After that the generate report code ( lets assume that it is implemented as a class) will refer to the database to get the required info to generate this report and then the info will "propagates upward" until it reaches the UI again to be viewed by the user. So is this right ?  In other words , is this what is the meaning of the User interface management ? and do I understand the mechanism of this architecture ?

Comment: Please cite the source where you got that diagram from.

Comment: Software Engineering by Ian Sommerville

Comment: Can you help me understand why you deleted your question?  It is often considered impolite to delete your question after you have received an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions  and answers that will help not only the person who asked the question but also others in the future who might have a similar question.  Deleting after receiving answers prevents others from benefiting from the answers in the future.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I have posted it in software engineering  stackexchange . As I have realized that to post it there is better . https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408559/a-question-regarding-the-layered-architecture

Answer (score 1):

"User Interface Management" does not have a standard accepted definition that I am aware of, so you'll have to work out what they mean by it based on context.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say precisely what that means, but in most GUI systems, the user interface can be understood as having two broad parts:

1. The part that each program (usually referred to as "the client") manages itself.
2. The part that is managed centrally.

For example, each program is generally responsible for drawing the contents of its own window, but a window from one client can cover the window from another client, and this has to be handled by part of the operating system, usually referred to as the window manager. Similarly, some central component has to handle keyboard and mouse events and decide which application window should receive them.

In Windows NT, the architecture looks like this:

[image: Windows NT architecture]

Clients (i.e. applications) use the Win32 subsystem (which is a combination of various shared libraries such as user32.dll) to manage their own windows, but arbitrating between windows and handling the display as a whole is implemented as a system service (win32k.sys).

MacOS has a similar structure, with most applications using [Cocoa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoa_(API)) to manage their windows. The component that handles central management is called [Quartz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_(graphics_layer)).

And on more traditional Unix systems like Linux, the [X Window System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) has a fairly traditional client/server architecture too.